# Check if eventbridge schedule is existing

Tags: python, lambda, aws-event-bridge

I want to Check if eventbridge schedule is existing , Or not ..
When I use `response=client.get_schedule( Name='Name of the schedule' )`

It will return the details of the schedule if it's existing , But it will throw exception and will not return any values if it's not existing which breaks the code .
I'm using python on lambda .

Comment: Which client are you working with,  boto3 [event bridge docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/events.html#client) (currently v1.26.82) and do not see a `get_schedule()` method on EventBridge client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would be to wrap this line around with

```
try:
    response = client.describe_rule(Name='Name of the schedule')
except ResourceNotFoundException as err:
    # decide what to do here
```

boto3 docs eventbridge client [describe_rule](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/events/client/describe_rule.html)